# Can't ping devices on LAN

Tags: networking, network-interface, iproute, dnsmasq

I've got 2 Access Points attached to my laptop's ethernet port via a PoE switch. I've assigned static IPs & names to them with `dnxmasq` (successfully, I believe). However, ping and ssh say they're unreachable. So what have I missed, and how can I successfully `ping 10.0.0.10`?

More info: The dnsmasq logs confirm that the DHCP transaction was successful, and my APs should now be `10.0.0.10` and `10.0.0.11`, on an infinite lease. My laptop's ethernet interface `enp0s31f6` is on `10.0.0.0`, and I can `ping 10.0.0.0`, even without dnsmasq running.

*(Stack-wise, I'm using systemd, wayland, sway (started from console, no logind / display manager). `iwd` for wireless (so no NetworkManager). I'm listing these in case there's some GDM/Gnome/NM magic that would set up interfaces better or something)*

My main theory is that something I haven't done with either `ip` or `dnsmasq` somehow "enables routing".

To start the system running, I do (as root):

```
# ip link set enp0s31f6 up
# ip addr add 10.0.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6
# systemctl start dnsmasq.service
```

Here's the machine that doesn't go "ping":

```
$ ping 10.0.0.10
PING 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.0 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.0 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.0 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
[...]
```

On the plus side it appears to know that pings to this IP need to come from the ethernet interface's IP. Worth adding that iwd / wifi networking works fine and I can ping hosts on the internet.

I haven't used `ip route` to set anything manually, but it looks like it does the right thing(?):

```
$ ip route | grep 10.0
10.0.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.0
```

`ip address` confirms that I've added the 10.* subnet (if that's the right term). I've snipped the output here to show only the relevant interface:

```
$ ip addr
...
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:6a:64:1f:02:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.0/16 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ea6a:64ff:fe1f:264/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
```

Here's `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```ini
interface=enp0s31f6
dhcp-authoritative
bind-interfaces

# Static IPs: (mac, name, IP, lease-time)
dhcp-host=e8:6a:64:1f:02:64,host,10.0.0.0,infinite
dhcp-host=78:8a:20:06:b1:b0,ap1,10.0.0.10,infinite
dhcp-host=18:e8:29:47:66:a4,ap2,10.0.0.11,infinite

# Dynamic range of IPs to supply:
dhcp-range=10.0.1.0,10.0.100.255,255.255.0.0,5m # TODO change 5m @@

## Probably-irrelevant DNS stuff:
# Set gateway / probably only for internet forwarding
dhcp-option=3,10.0.0.0
# Set DNS servers to announce / ?
dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.0
```

Comment: You add wrong IP address `ip add addr 10.0.0.0`. This is the address of network, the first usable address is `10.0.0.1`

Comment: Oh, interesting, thank you! I'll try incrementing it everywhere. For that specific command, I thought `ip addr add 10.0.0.0/16 dev ...` *should* be the address of the network, because /16 is effectively a netmask and it's supplying a range (I'm assuming it means "handle this IP range with this interface")

Comment: No, you're saying that 10.0.0.0 is to be _my_ IP address, and then because you've provided the /16 it's possible to derive the network address directly (see `ipcalc` for a visual explanation)

Comment: Solved!!! Thanks @RomeoNinov :) If you want to paste it into a proper answer I'll click things until they all turn green!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config you set IP address wrongly:

```
ip add addr 10.0.0.0/16
```

`10.0.0.0` is the address of network, the first usable address is `10.0.0.1`

Also you should check below you use the same address as gateway and DNS (in DHCP config)